# Sum different values of same type in same column in one SQL query

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, case

At the moment im doing the following to count the payment methods in different languages in a column:

```
$sql = "SELECT `payment`, count(*) as number FROM Test GROUP BY `payment` ";
```

**Result:**

```
Cash 2
Bar 4
Credit-Card 5
Kreditkarte 8
Invoice 12
Rechnung 27
```

Any idea how to sum the same payment methods in different languages in one SQL query to get the following without the part in the brackets obviously:

```
Bar 6 (sum of Cash and Bar)
Kreditkarte 13 (sum of Credit-Card and Kreditkarte)
Rechnung 39 (sum of Invoice and Rechnung)
```

**Table Name:** Test

```
payment       
===========
Cash
Bar
Credit-Card
Kreditkarte
Invoice
Rechnung
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression that changes `'Cash'` to `'Bar'`, `'Credit-Card'` to `'Kreditkarte'` and `'Invoice'` to `'Rechnung'` and group by its result:

```
SELECT CASE payment
         WHEN 'Cash' THEN 'Bar'
         WHEN 'Credit-Card' THEN 'Kreditkarte'
         WHEN 'Invoice' THEN 'Rechnung'
         ELSE payment
       END AS payment, 
       COUNT(*) AS number 
FROM Test 
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: THX a lot, any way to select another column to refine the statement with WHERE?

Comment: @evavienna you can select another column if you use it also in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: really - never did this before any hint? normally i do `select payment, driver...`

Comment: @evavienna in a query with a group by clause most databases do not allow the selection of any non-aggregated column if it does not also appear in the GROUP BY clause. MySql allows it (under conditions), but its result is undefined. This means that if in the group there are many different values for the column `driver` for each payment, the value returned for `driver` will be an arbitrary one.